# JavaScript Regular expressions, match and replace link

Tags: javascript, regex

please help me

```
 <html>
  <body>
       http://domainname.com/abc/xyz.zip
       http://domainname2.com/abc/xyz.zip 

 </body>
 </html>
```

I want replace with link and out put like

```
 <html>
  <body>
      <a href="http://domainname.com/abc/xyz.zip">http://domainname.com/abc/xyz.zip</a>
      <a href="http://domainname2.com/abc/xyz.zip">http://domainname2.com/abc/xyz.zip</a>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Great Thank

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace URL with HTML Links javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/replace-url-with-html-links-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You [should not use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to parse HTML.

Comment: He's not, he wants a regular expression to replace text with HTML.

Comment: Except that this requires you to be aware of the link's context. What if the link is already inside of an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function linkify(element) {
    var children = element.childNodes,
        stub = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i<children.length; ++i) {
        if (children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var parts = children[i].nodeValue.split(/(http:\/\/\S+)/);  // adjust regex
            if (parts.length > 1) {
                for (var j=0; j<parts.length; ++j) {
                    if (j % 2 === 1) {
                        var link = document.createElement("a");
                        link.setAttribute("href", parts[j]);
                        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[j]));
                        stub.appendChild(link);
                    } else {
                        stub.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[j]));
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        stub.appendChild(children[i]);
    }
    document.write(stub.childNodes.length);
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(stub, element);
}
linkify(document.body);
```

This is pure DOM manipulation. This `linkify` function expects the argument to be a *HTMLElement*. You just need to adjust the regular expression to grab the URLs.